# child processes executed sequentially

Tags: c, linux, parallel-processing, fork

My code was like this:

```
struc s1{
 int s1_length;
};

void main(){
    ...
    int i;
    int *fds = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10 *2);

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        pipe(fds +i*2);

    struct s1 s;
    s.s1_length = 0;
    int s_size;
    ...
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
       child_pid = fork();
       if(child_pid == 0){
           close(fds[i*2]);
           s = getS(...);
           s_size = s.s1_length;
           write(fds[i*2+1], &s_size, ..);
           write(fds[i*2+1], &s, sizeof(s_size));
           close(fds[i*2+1]);
           printf("execting child %d..\n", i);
           exit(0);
       } else{
           close(fds[i*2+1]);
           read(fds[i*2], &s_size, ..);
           read(fds[i*2],&s,sizeof(s_size));
           printf("execting parent %d..\n", i);
           close(fds[i*2]);
       }
    }
}
```

The output was like

```
execting child 0..
execting parent 0..
execting child 1..
execting parent 1..
execting child 2..
execting parent 1..
···
```

looks like they are running sequentially, but since I use `fork()` of course I want them runnning parallelly, does anyone know what went wrong here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. By brief inspection of your code, it looks as if the parent must receive a signal from child N before it creates child N+1, so naturally they run sequentially. What else did you intend with all those pipes?

Comment: You'll need something like `select` `epoll`, etc after the loop to detect which pipes are ready to be read from and do the reading there, *after* you created the children

Comment: @Beta Hi, thank you for your reply. I try to let child processes write some values and pass them to parent processes, so each parent process return of `fork()` should wait until its child process gives it returned values. But it does not need to be sequentially

Comment: @ikegami but 10 pipes are created for 10 child processes, I thought every single pipe can then be read or wrote without influence from other pipes?

Comment: Re "*I thought every single pipe can then be read or wrote without influence from other pipes?*", They can. Noone said otherwise

Comment: You do realize there's only one parent process (one process calling `fork`), right? And if it's blocked calling `read`, it's not calling `fork`

Comment: The reads will be sequential, yes. A task can't do more than one thing at a time, so it can't read from more than one children at at time. But it will allow the children to run in parallel.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks you for your explanation ^^ Yes, I did realize that. the sequential reading of parent process won't be a problem for my application, but from the output, I think it executed not only sequentially in parent process but also child processes, like it was only one child process running in a time, and this gonna be a problem for me.

Comment: Re "*I think it executed not only sequentially in parent process but also child processes,*", Yes, the way you have it now, that is the case. As explained above, you only create the second child after the first is done, the third after the second is done, etc.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks a lot!! I finally get it^^ I will check how I can use `epoll`, so I should use it inside the parent process where a `fork()` returns?

Comment: You want to use it after after creating all the children.

Comment: If the parent doesn't need to do anything else, you don't actually need `select`/`epoll`/whatever; You can just read from each pipe in (any) order. But again, *after* creating all the children

Comment: (That also assumes the children filling up the pipes won't prevent them from doing any other work)